# Mplayer - Change track, play/pause with command line

Tags: command, shortcut, mplayer

Mplayer provides shortcuts to change the track and play/pause the music but they only work if the mplayer window has the focus.

Is it possible, for example, to change the track currently played in mplayer with a command line? In that case, I could assign this command to a shortcut and use it even if mplayer does not have the focus.

All I found on google was how to use mplayer to play files or which shortcuts to change track when the window has the focus.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually in the middle of trying to do this exact thing! I am going to share what I have discovered so far in case it helps anyone.

I have not been able to find a way to play/pause tracks. However, I have been able to change tracks, at least in terms of going to the next track.

I have found 2 ways so far: Using `/proc/$pid/fd/0` and Named Pipes (FIFOs). Explaining FIFOs is a little harder (I just recently learned of them) so I will do that last.

### Modifying STDIN via `/proc/$pid/fd/0`

We can communicate with a process in a different terminal session by redirecting input to the process' file definitions directory at `/proc/$pid/fd/` where `$pid` is the process' PID.

Firstly, find the process ID using `pidof`. Make sure `mplayer` is actually running!

```sh
$ pidof mplayer
```

This will output the PID of `mplayer`. Using this `$PID`, we can input what we want to STDIN for `mplayer` by redirecting it to `/proc/$PID/fd/0`. (Note, `0` refers to STDIN, `1` to STDOUT, etc.). An example:

```sh
$ echo "p" > /proc/$PID/fd/0
```

This has the effect of changing the tracks for `mplayer`.

However, even though I used `p` in my example, I have found that you can `echo` anything (including nothing) and it will still accomplish the same goal of changing the track no matter what you input.

### Named Pipes

Also called `FIFO`s, named pipes, just like regular pipes (`|`), redirect output to other processes. The main difference is that these are part of the filesystem and can be used to communicate between different terminal sessions.

To start off, create a new named pipe anywhere in your filesystem. I chose `/tmp/`.

```sh
$ mkfifo /tmp/mp3control.pipe
```

Then start `mplayer` redirecting its STDIN to the named pipe.

```sh
$ mplayer -playlist brutal_tunez.txt < /tmp/mp3control.pipe
```

It will look like the process hangs and that's because it is expecting the other side to input something.

Now open up a new terminal and input stuff into the pipe.

```sh
$ echo "p" > /tmp/mp3control.pipe
```

You will hear music start to play from `mplayer`. Again, just like before, any further inputs to the pipe will just change tracks.

I believe this has something to do with the way `mplayer` handles STDIN and is not the same thing as entering `p` to play or pause music.

I will continue looking into this but I would love to hear from someone if I made a mistake somewhere. All in all, this might end up being something where the amount of time spent is not worth it, to be honest. (But we still must!)

Comment: Just to add some (I hope) useful info: p (=pause), q (=quit), st (=stop=quit), o (=osd), m (=mute). I use "echo p > /tmp/pipe"